# Low search status example

Tags: low-search

I wondered if there was an example of using statuses as a dropdown? I'm trying to search by a couple of options with not much success. I want to filter by some statuses but never show items in another status.

My dropdown currently looks like this:

```
<select style="width:200px;" name="status[]" >
    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="Shortlisted">Shortlisted</option>
    <option value="Winner">Winner</option>
</select>
```

My results tag looks like this

```
{exp:low_search:results 
    channel="applications|bursary_applications"
    status="not closed|In progress"
    query="{segment_3}"
    dynamic="off"
    limit="50"
    paginate="bottom"
    collection="applications|bursary_applications"
    child:bursary_app_competition_rel="{segment_2}"
}
```

(when the page is first loaded without search terms I want to make sure 'In progress' is not shown - or I'd settle for a default of 'Completed'!)

Many thanks!

Note: I also posted this question here: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_search_status_example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer here as well as in the GetSat thread for visibility.

Any parameters set in the Results tag will always overwrite the corresponding given parameters from a search query. If you want to default a certain value, you could use simple conditionals to check for an encoded query in the URI and set certain parameters accordingly. For example:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    query="{segment_3}"
    {if segment_3 == ''}status="not closed|In progress"{/if}
}
```

In addition to that, if you want 'All' entries to exclude certain values, just define those in the 'All' option of the drop down. For example:

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="not closed|In progress">All</option>
    <option>Completed</option>
    <option>Shortlisted</option>
    <option>Winner</option>
</select>
```

Note that if you don't add a value-attribute to an option-element, the text inside the option-element will be used as value.

Also note you don't need the multiple value syntax in the name (`status[]`), as you're only selecting a single value.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, here's how I've just implemented a Status search option in my Orders search form:

```
{exp:low_search:form query="{segment_3}" result_page="orders/search-results" channel="orders" status="Processing|Awaiting Payment|Complete|Cancelled"}
    <div class="searchbar">
        <input type="text" name="search:title" value="" placeholder="Order No" />
        <select name="status[]">
            <option value="not open|closed">Status</option>
            <option>Processing</option>
            <option>Awaiting Payment</option>
            <option>Complete</option>
            <option>Cancelled</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="search:order_billing_first_name" value="" placeholder="First name" />
        <input type="text" name="search:order_billing_last_name" value="" placeholder="Surname" />
        <input type="text" name="search:order_billing_city" value="" placeholder="Town" />
        <input type="text" name="search:order_billing_zip" value="" placeholder="Postcode" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

And here is how my Results page is output:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" channel="orders" {if status == ""}status="Processing|Awaiting Payment|Complete|Cancelled"{/if} limit="20"}
    {if no_results}<p>No results matched your query.</p>{/if}
    Order: {title}
    Status: {status}
    Name: {order_billing_first_name} {order_billing_last_name}
    Address: {order_billing_city} {order_billing_zip}
    Total: &pound;{order_total}
    Date: {entry_date format="%l %j%S %F %Y &nbsp; %g:%i&nbsp;%a"}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```